# D3 JS column chart without or avoid range / rangebands / rangeroundbands

Tags: d3.js, column-chart

I am working on a multi series column chart using ordinal scale with date or month name on x-axis (not using time scale). We have huge data by date or month to present while pulling incrementally by hitting the service. Due to rangeBands or rangeRoundBands methods, the columns shrunk and the depiction is confined to svg width.

We need to allow scrolling horizontally while providing some interaction on columns. For that we had drawn all columns and their parent SVG 'g' elements inside a foreignObject with a div and another SVG doc.

Now, is there a way I can avoid rangeRoundBands, so that the columns spread horizontally without getting fit in the available space.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking -- of course you don't *need* to use any of the methods D3 provides.

Comment: Seems like a good time for horizontal panning: http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you. Yes, this is something similar was looking for.